# Java swing layouts and/or labels not in order

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jlabel

I have got a window that should display the following:

- JLablel "Have you used GUI before?" on the top, centered
- two radioButtons "Yes" and "No" below it, somewhat in the center, a little bit towards the left
- a JButton "NEXT" in the bottom-right corner

All three elements should have green font and darkGrey background.
The problem is that the window which is showing up, does not look like I would like it to.
And this is my code:

```
        yesButton = new JRadioButton(yes);
        //yesButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B); // doesn't work?
        yesButton.setActionCommand(yes);            

        noButton = new JRadioButton(no);
        // noButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C); // doesn't work?
        noButton.setActionCommand(no);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(yesButton);
        group.add(noButton);

        nextButton = new JButton("NEXT");
        nextButton.setActionCommand(next);

        yesButton.addActionListener(this);
        noButton.addActionListener(this);
        nextButton.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        radioPanel.add(yesButton);
        radioPanel.add(noButton);

        add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        // setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        // radioPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(250, 250, 20, 20));
            // there is no difference between the above two, right?

        String q = "Have you used GUI before?";
        JPanel area = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        area.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        JLabel textLabel2 = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">"
                + q + "</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textLabel2.setForeground(Color.green);
        Font font2 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30);
        textLabel2.setFont(font2);
        //textLabel2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 250, 0)); //top, left, bottom, right
        area.add(textLabel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        area.add(nextButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I feel I'm nearly there, thanks for any help!

--EDIT--
A screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and attach it to your question? That would help us troubleshoot the layout issue more directly, if we can see how it lays out on your screen.

Comment: Good point, should have thought about it in the first place

Comment: 1) Still no SSCCE?  2) When preparing that screenshot, be sure to check out [How do I create a great screen-shot of a problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-great-screen-shot-of-a-problem/) 3) It might also pay to describe (with arrows drawn on the screenshot) how extra space should be assigned when the user increases the size of the frame. 4) It seems like the two `JRadioButton` instances should be replaced by one `JCheckBox`.

Comment: 1) Still learning... I reduced the code to minimum, 2) will read it and 3) user is not allowed to change the size ;)

Comment: That is not a SSCCE. We want "minimum code" that compiles and executes and shows the described problem.

Comment: While you're learning, please learn how **not** to revert the post to the incorrectly spelled (e.g. JLablel .. radioButtons), poorly formatted original that I improved on.  ;)

Comment: My fault again ;) "Nobody is prefect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get much control with just a BorderLayout.  Try something else like MigLayout or one of the other many many layout managers Java has (GridBag, Box, [etc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)).

In [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) it would look something like:

```
area.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));

area.add(textLabel2, "wrap");
area.add(radioPanel, "wrap");
area.add(nextButton, "tag right");
```

Comment: I didn't know which Layout to choose, but Border looks most friendly to me and also I'm not planning to make a very complex windows - two JLabels, two textFields and a JButton is most what I need, so I thought I can do it just with the BorderLayout.

Comment: BorderLayout just doesn't do much at all.  If you stick with the built-in layout managers, you'll find that you nest panels with different layouts to get what you need.  I really like MigLayout because it is simple to do most layouts, and it combines features of other layout managers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use nested panels.

1. for the BorderLayout.NORTH you can add the JLabel directly. You will need to set the horizontal text alignment to center.
2. for the radio buttons you can create a JPanel with a FlowLayout and then add the buttons to the panel and add the panel to the CENTER.
3. for the button you add the button to a panel using a FlowLayout that is right aligned, then add the panel to the SOUTH.

There are other choices. You could also use a Vertical BoxLayout as the layout of the main panel and then add child panels to it.

Comment: Thanks. FlowLayout is the default one, isn't it?

Comment: +1 For `BoxLayout`. @Hurdler, The default layout for a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`.

Comment: @Moonbeam  Ever since Sun changed the default layout of top-level containers from `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout` some time ago, I have decided it is best to explicitly set *every* layout. YMMV.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson yes just in case if you add only one `J/Component` :-), then is used `LayoutManager - BorderLayout.CENTER`, or am I wrong :-)

Comment: @mKorbel  Yes, the default position for `BorderLayout` when no constraint is supplied, is the `CENTER`.  I hold more confidence in that one, since it is documented in the JavaDocs *"As a convenience, BorderLayout interprets the absence of a string specification the same as the constant CENTER:"* ( but I always explicitly specify it anyway ;).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson you are right, for top-level Container, but how do you switch from JPanel/FlowLayout to JFrame, JDialog, JWindow/BorderLayout is a mystery to me, my mistake  :-)